# How to sumif a row?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

My table looks like this

```
Month     January    February
Apple       50           50
Orange      10           10
Grapes      5             5
```

When I try to `sumif Apple` like `=sumif(A2:A4,"Apple",B2:C4)` it only gives me 50 from January and not the whole line. The answer I need is 100.

How should I edit the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUMPRODUCT` instead: `=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A4="Apple")*B2:C4)`